# How do I convert this to a linear integer program?

Tags: integer-programming

I have the following optimization problem.

\begin{align}
    \text{Maximize } & \sum_{k=1}^P x_{i,k} \mu_{k} \\
    \text{Subject to } & \sum_{k=1}^P\sum_{l=1}^P x_{i,k}x_{i,l} \sigma_{k, l} \geq \epsilon_i \\
    & \sum_{k=1}^P\sum_{l=1}^P x_{i,k}x_{j,l}^*\sigma_{k, l} \leq \gamma_{i, j} \; \forall \; 1 \leq j \leq i - 1 \\
    & \sum_{k=1}^P x_{i, k} = K
\end{align}

With decision variables $x_{i, k} \in \{0, 1\} \; \forall k \in \{1, 2, \dots, P\}$ and all other variables constant.

My problem is that the first constraint is not linear. In the [paper which this program is adapted from](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.01455.pdf) (page 12, eq 2.14), they state "We can introduce auxiliary variables to make this formulation
linear as is standard in many integer programming formulations.", but I don't know enough about integer linear programming to know how to do that.

How do I make this constraint linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me introduce variable $y_{i,k,l}= x_{i,k}x_{i,l}$,

We want $$y_{i,k,l} = \begin{cases} 1, & x_{i,k}=1 \text{ and } x_{i,l}=1\\ 0, & \text{Otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Let's replace the first constraint by:

$$y_{i,k,l} \geq x_{i,k} + x_{i,l}-1$$

$$y_{i,k,l} \leq x_{i,k}$$

$$y_{i,k,l} \leq x_{i,l}$$

$$0 \leq y_{i,k,l} \leq 1$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^P\sum_{l=1}^P y_{i,k,l} \sigma_{k, l} \geq \epsilon_i$$